# Swap Batteries MacBook Pro & MacBook Unibody

Tags: mac, hardware, battery

My MacBook's (late 2008, unibody, 13") battery has just become very bad. I also have a MacBook Pro (mid 2012, 15") which has a *still-ok* battery. Now, since I take my MacBook (the old one) everywhere I would like it to have a good battery life.

Can I swap the batteries of the two Macs? I saw that the battery of my old MacBook has 45Wh and the newer one has 77.5Wh, is that going to be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Will you even be able to fit the 15" MacBook Pro's battery into the 13" MacBook?
2. Messing with power like this only result in broken things.

I highly recommend to get a new battery from Apple if it's still available. Or perhaps from a reliable third party.

Comment: **1.** I think so, I haven't tried but it looked like it would fit... **2.** Probably, right? Thats why I asked first. Thanks :)

Comment: @LinusG. I still don't recommend it. You're dealing with 2 completely different models from different years (4 years apart). Edit: yup on 2. This will break things. I don't want you ending up with a broken laptop.